# How to pass deployment settings to application?

Tags: qooxdoo

I am trying to deploy a Qooxdoo web application backed by CherryPy-hosted web services onto a server. However, I need to configure the client-side Qooxdoo application with the hostname of the server on which the application resides so that that the Ajax callbacks resolve to the right host. I have a feeling I can use the capabilities of the generate.py Qooxdoo script to generate client-side code with this appropriately set, but reading through the docs hasn't helped make it clear how yet. Anyone have any tips?

(FWIW, I know how I'd approach this using something like PHP and a different client-side framework like Echo 3--I'd have the index file be a PHP file that reads a local system configuration file prior to sending back client-side code. In this case, however, the generate.py file is a necessary part of the toolchain, so I can't see how to do it so simply.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use qx.core.Enviroment class to add/get configuration for your project. The recommend way is only during compilation time, but there is a hack if you want to configure your application during run time.

**Configuration during compilation time**

If you want to configure the environment during compilation time see [this](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.2/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_articles.html#environment-key).

In both cases after you add any environmental variable to your application, it can be accessed using the [qx.core.Environment.get](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/api/#qx.core.Environment~get!method_public) method.

**On run time**

**WARNING this method isn't supported/documented from qooxdoo. Basically it's a hack**

If you want to make available some environment configuration on run time you have to do this before qooxdoo loads. In order to this you could add some javascript into your webpage e.g.

```
window.qx = { };
window.qx.$$environment = {
 "myawsomeapp.hostname": "example.org",
};
```

This should be added somewhere in your page before the qooxdoo start loading otherwise it will not have the desirable effect. The advantage of this method is that you can push configuration to the client e.g. some api keys that may be different between instances of your application.

Comment: Configuration of environment keys during compile time is the only way to preset values for `qx.core.Environment` - the method you've shown to do it at runtime involves modifying undocumented configuration and is not supported.

Comment: @johnspackman yes you are right, I will add warning to this method.

Comment: This works like a champ! I created two new build options in my config.json, each customizing the environment setting I reference from within the application.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to compose your AJAX URL on the fly from `window.location`; ideally, you would be able to use `window.location.origin` which for this StackOverflow website would be "https://stackoverflow.com" but there are issues with that on IE.

A cross platform solution is:

```
var urlRoot = window.location.protocol + "//" + 
  window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' +
  window.location.port: '');
```

This means your URL will always be correct, even if the server name changes (eg your on a test server instead of production).

See here for more details:
https://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Ya, I considered this, but then I think loading the app from local files would break, no?

Comment: yes you're correct, in which case Stelios' answer is the only solution without hard coding - although you will get CORS issues (unless you're already responding to OPTIONS requests and explicitly providing the "Access-*" response headers)